# I am trying to show an inequality involving the product of three inner product terms

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, inner-products

Define the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ for continuous functions defined on $[0,1]$ as:

$$\langle\,f\mid g\rangle=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)g(x)e^{\rho x}dx,$$

where $\rho$ is a real number.

I wish to show that:

\begin{multline*}
\langle 1\mid (1-t)^{a-b-1}\rangle \cdot \langle t^{b}\mid (1-t)^{a-2}\rangle \cdot \langle t^{1+b}\mid (1-t)^{a-1}\rangle\geq  \\
\geq \langle 1\mid (1-t)^{a-b}\rangle \cdot \langle t^{1+b},(1-t)^{a-2}\rangle \cdot \langle t^{b},(1-t)^{a-1}\rangle,
\end{multline*}

where $a>1$ and $a>b>0$. Thanks a lot for any help!

The original (and equivalent) inequality I wished to establish is
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\langle t\mid (1-t)^{a-b-1}\rangle . \langle 1\mid t^{b}(1-t)^{a-1}%
\rangle . \langle 1\mid t^{1+b}(1-t)^{a-2}\rangle  \\
&&+\langle 1\mid (1-t)^{a-b-1}\rangle . \langle t\mid t^{b}(1-t)^{a-1}%
\rangle . \langle 1\mid t^{1+b}(1-t)^{a-2}\rangle  \\
&\geq &\langle 1\mid (1-t)^{a-b-1}\rangle . \langle 1,t^{b}(1-t)^{a-1}%
\rangle . \langle t,t^{1+b}(1-t)^{a-2}\rangle .
\end{eqnarray*}

So far I have tried to use some Cauchy-Schwarz inequality by gathering terms in
couples. Unsuccessful. I am thinking that some extension of the CS
inequality to dimension 3 might provide some lead.

Comment: What have you tried? How convoluted is it going to be if you integrate by parts the right hand side a few times?

Comment: did you try integrating by part $\int_0^1 e^t t^b (1-t)^{a-2} dt$ ?

Comment: Indeed, I have tried integrating by part but it just messes things up.

Comment: I am currently trying to prove the inequality by generalizing to the case of three functions some techniques developed in the paper SEVERAL INTERESTING INTEGRAL INEQUALITIES BY WENJUN LIU, QUˆO ´ C-ANH NGˆO AND VU NHAT HUY, Journal of Mathematical Inequalities, Vol 3, 2, 2009, 201-212.